# .NET console output bypassing redirection

Tags: .net, console, io-redirection

The *Console* class in .NET supports writing text to [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) and [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)). However, I believe there is another stream that can be written to, that cannot be redirected.

See *[Display & Redirect Output](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php)*

A batch file could achieve this like so:

`echo hello > CON`

How could this stream, or the effect non-redirectable output, be achieved in C#?

Comment: Not a stream, winapi functions you have to pinvoke.  Like WriteFile() to the "CONOUT$" device or WriteConsole().

Comment: @HansPassant if you add this as an answer, i'll accept - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **Hans Passant**, the following solution works (with a graceful fallback to `Console.Out` if the `CONOUT$` 'file' could not be created):

```
public static class Progress
{
    private static readonly TextWriter _writer;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateFile(
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string filename,
          uint fileAccess,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileShare share,
         IntPtr securityAttributes, // optional SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES struct or IntPtr.Zero
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode creationDisposition,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAttributes flagsAndAttributes,
         IntPtr templateFile);

    const int FILE_ACCESS_WRITE = 0x40000000;

    static Progress()
    {
        var realStdOut = new SafeFileHandle(CreateFile("CONOUT$", FILE_ACCESS_WRITE, FileShare.ReadWrite, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 0, IntPtr.Zero), true);

        _writer = !realStdOut.IsInvalid
            ? new StreamWriter(new FileStream(realStdOut, FileAccess.Write))
            : Console.Out;
    }

    public static void WriteLine(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        _writer.WriteLine(format, args);
        _writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

Sometimes when debugging the app via Visual Studio I found that it failed to create the `CONOUT$` file - hence the graceful fallback.